# JavaScript array from PHP string

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am developing an application having more than thousands of values. I am trying to make a dynamic array in JavaScript. I'm using AJAX to get my values. So I have to create a string from PHP ,it should able to convert from string to array in JavaScript.

How can I make a string in PHP that can be converted to array in JavaScript?

Comment: you should make json string in PHP and then json to JS object for javascript logic. http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: This isn't hard to do (`json_encode` is your friend), but "more than thousands of values" suggests you might want to rethink your application architecture...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for JSON and [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
$string = json_encode($array);
```

The content of the string will be the array written in valid javascript.

Comment: Thanks for instant comment. Actually i want to know how i can make this string from PHP if values generate by a loop. ?

Comment: Fas K K Fasil: json_encode accepts an array, so you need to create an array in PHP first, like $array = array(1, 2, 3). Can't give you exact code, because I don't know how your application works.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON notation to create a string of values and then read it from JS. The simplest way to do this is something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myPHPData = <?php echo json_encode($myData); ?>;
alert myPHPData; // now you have access to it in JS
</script>
```

Comment: json_encode is not useful if string generated by ajax. There i used spli();

Answer (score 0):

if you dont intend to use json , you can do something of this kind..

you can create a string of this kind in php (separate it by any delimiter)

```
      $arr = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7" ;
```

in javascript you can convert this to array using split function

```
      //make an ajax call and get this string (say str)
      arr = str.split(";");
```

split() returns an array

```
 arr[0] is 1  
 arr[1] is 2
 and so on !!
```